# How to connect MongoDB using Mongoose in Node.js using await/async

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, async-await

```
const express = require("express")
const app = express();
const mongoose=require("mongoose")


async  () =>
{
  try {
    let res=await  mongoose.connect(uri)
    console.log("Succesfully logged")
   } catch (error) {
     console.log("Error",error)
   }

app.get("/", (req, res) =>{
//stuff
}
```

I tried this, but my async function isnt being called, how do i make the server wait and execute the async function first. I want to check if the database is connected. but the code is just skipping over it.

EDIT:

```
const verification= async  () =>
{
  try {
    let res=await  mongoose.connect(uri)
    console.log("Succesfully logged")
   } catch (error) {
     console.log("Error",error)
   }

  }
   const Itemx=new mongoose.Schema
   {
    Item:String
   }

   const Items= mongoose.model('Item',Itemx)

   //Items.

 verification()
```

So, i tried this, and it works but issue is if i decide to close the connection later, its done synchronously which i am trying to avoid, i cant use await on verification because its outside of the async function.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Immediately invoked function expression` to create an async function where you can wait for the connection before starting the server.

```js
const express = require("express")
const app = express()
const mongoose = require("mongoose")

// Setup app router
// app.get(...
// app.post(...

(async () => { // async function
  try {
    await mongoose.connect(uri); // wait for connection

    app.listen(PORT, () => {
      console.log("Server is listening at " + PORT);
    });
  } catch (error) {
    console.console.log("Something went wrong!!!");
    console.error(error);
  }
})(); // Immediate invoke
```